# relative positioning of text object in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity I want to align a UI text object next to another text object based on the length of the first object. Like: "[Aladinn] says: hello World".
Where "[Aladinn]" is the (clickable) first text and "says: hello world" the second text.
Obviously the length of the first text can vary.

I found some ways to set the length of a text box based on its contents, but is there a way to attach the start of the second text to the end of the first text while keeping them separate objects?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`Text#preferredWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-preferredWidth.html)

The description on the documentation page is not super helpful, but this value is "how long does this bit of text *want* to be?"  `PreferredHeight` is the same, except for height.

So to find out where the text of another object ends, you have to get it's Text component and query its preferred width and voila, you have its size (in pixels, which for Canvas objects is almost certainly going to be its scene size as well, unless you've done naughty things with scale).

I use this in [one of my projects](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/game/GuiManager.cs#L64) to make a mouse-over tooltip look nice, by trying various width and height values until it reaches a desired ratio.  It's kind of complex, but that has to do with the fact that preferred width and height assume certain things (preferred width wants to have the string displayed on a single line, while preferred height takes into account the *current* width and assumes that the line wraps are included in the desired height).

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your description of the problem, i would sugest using a script to alter The text's string, instead of using two seperate text objects.

This would be fine for your description of the problem:

```
public string name;
public string flavorText;
public Text textUIComponnent;
```

then somewhere in the code, inside Start for example:

```
void Start {
textUIComponnent.text = name + " " + flavorText;
[...]
}
```